# Better application switcher for Budgie desktop

Tags: software-recommendation, application-switcher

I'm using Budgie Desktop currently, and I really enjoy it. It's got good battery life, customizability, stability and speed, but there's just one thing that bothers me; it doesn't have a real app switcher. Pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd> will switch apps, but no dialog appears, and it doesn't allow me to select an app I want to see; it just calls them all to front, on at a time.

Because of this, I've been looking for some third party app switcher that'll show a dialog and let me select the app to switch to instead of just pulling everything to the front. Right now, I'm using `skippy-xd`, which is an exposé-style switcher. It's OK, but I'd prefer the linear method that Unity and GNOME use.

Googling has turned up nothing. I think I'm just not doing it correctly.

Are there any standalone app/task switchers (besides `skippy-xd`) available for Ubuntu or Linux in general?

Comment: +1 for letting us know Budgie exists and may address battery life questions many AU users have posted.

Comment: +1 for asking the question. I too was looking for it

Comment: I voted for this question because I was also annoyed by the default app switcher in Budgie, but it seems to have been just upgraded (27/07/2017) because it does now have a window listing the running applications. Much better!

Answer (score 2):

Please note that the <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> behaviour is built into `budgie-wm` itself. I intend to add graphical switching in Budgie 11, which is currently in active development.

Budgie 12 will see deeper window management changes as we reduce our dependency on GNOME.

Comment: I managed to disable Budgie's Alt Tab using dconf editor. Fossfreedom told me that there is progress being made, but I'd like something in the meantime, if a solution exists.

Comment: I'm speaking as the author of Budgie itself. The only progress to be made in the meantime is by me. :)

Comment: From this message and your profile, I gathered that :p. I was just pointing out that I do know Budgie will eventually get a better app switcher.

Comment: Ah my bad :) Never know who knows who :P Budgie 11 will represent the single largest release we've ever done.. and 12 could be even bigger still. Derpy Alt+TAB is one of my pet hates fwiw, and I'll add it to the sinbin list later: https://github.com/budgie-desktop/info/blob/master/NEXT_NOTES.md

Comment: do you have an ETA on Budgie 11? so far I'm loving the desktop UI, the only sore spot is the alt+tab functionality.

Comment: Looks like you have an old Budgie then, as the ALT+Tab functionality was fixed in Budgie 10.3 (Graphical switcher)

Comment: Is there a reason that the version for 17.04 is only 10.2.9, when 10.3.1 is out for 16.04/10? I tried forcing 10.3.1 on 17.04 and it seems like it's having issues. Is that why?

Answer (score 1):

I strongly recommends [rofi](https://davedavenport.github.io/rofi/). It can be used as a window swticher and application runner. Realy neat.

Comment: This is exactly what I am looking for for a long time. THANK YOU VERY MUCH!